# MPMoviePlayer "Done" Button not working properly

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I tried **MPMoviePlayer** for playing an **audio file (mp3)** while testing i found that sometimes Done button stops responding. What can be the possible reason?? please help

Comment: If you need any help I suggest you post some code

Answer (score 1):

use

presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:

dismisMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:

Comment: that's solution only if you not using just the inner view of the media player controller ...